# Inserting an array into database

Tags: php

Does anyone have best practices when inserting an array into a database? I've used foreach loops with success in the past, as well as various array functions. Is there a better way?

Here is a sample code:

```
public function InsertRequests($id) {

$db = Database::getHandler();

$selected_requests = $this->GetRequests($this->allrequests);

  foreach($selected_requests as $requestid) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO requests (userid,requestid,date) VALUES (?,?,NOW())"; 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(2,$requestid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: very hard to answer with out seeing any data, db structure.

Comment: a best practice would to use an ORM or any CRUD abstraction layer. and for performance check batch inserting.

Comment: @j08691 Serializing/Deserializing is expensive and messy. Store each value in a separate row in the respective table.

Comment: Executing multiple INSERTs at once by separating them with a semicolon increases the speed of the total INSERT operation by a lot, so I'd go for that in this case.

Comment: Move the `prepare()` out of the loop, you don't need to prepare a new `stmt` on each iteration, you only need to bind the params and execute.

Comment: You could use http://www.propelorm.org/. If one of your model has a list of objects, you could insert it directly and seamlessly

Answer (score 1):

You can insert multiple records with a single query like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME ( fieldOne, fieldTwo, fieldThree ) VALUES 
( 'Jack', 'Nickholson', 'M' ), 
( 'Audrey', 'Hepburn', 'F' ),
( 'Salvador', 'Dali', 'M' )
...
```

So, prepare your INSERT syntax iterating over your data array in a regular loop or using custom query builder than execute it once. Better practice is using an ORM library like @Karoly's said.